# Problema con return back()->withInput(); Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, controller, entrada

Estoy tratando de retornar hacia atrás, con los valores del input pre cargados, aunque si muestra los mensajes de alerta que le estoy pasando, los inputs no se están cargando con los valores pasados, si no que salen vacíos. Aquí los códigos.

Controlador:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{ 
    $nombre=$request->input('nombre');
    $apellido=$request->input('apellido');
    $fecha_nacimiento=$request->input('fecha_nacimiento');
    $nacionalidad=$request->input('nacionalidad');
    $sexo=$request->input('sexo');
    $Sede=$request->input('Sede');
    $telefono_celular=$request->input('telefono_celular');
    $telefono_oficina=$request->input('telefono_oficina');
    $telefono_casa=$request->input('telefono_casa');
    $fecha_ini_cargo=$request->input('fecha_inicio');
    $fecha_fin_cargo=$request->input('fecha_fin');
    $razon_cambio=$request->input('razon_cambio');

    $a=1;
    if($a==1){

        \Alert::message(" $nombre $apellido no aparecen", 'success');
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput();

    }
}
```

Vista:

```
 @extends('layouts.principal')
 @section('content')
 {!! Alert::render() !!}

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1">
    <h2>Agregar Coordinador Administrador</h2>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12 " id="home">

    @if($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-dangerr" role="alert">
            <p>Por favor corrigue los errores:</p>
            <ul>
                @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{$error}}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif

        {!!Form::open(['route'=>'codadm.store','method'=>'POST'])!!}
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Nombre:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del Coordinador*" value="{{ old('nombre') }}" name="nombre" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Apellido:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Ingrese el apellido del Coordinador*" value="{{ old('apellido') }}" name="apellido" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Fecha de Nacimiento:') !!}
            <input type="date" class="form-control" step="1" value="{{ old('fecha_nacimiento') }}" min="1907-01-01" name="fecha_nacimiento" id="fecha_nacimiento" placeholder="Seleccione la fecha de Nacimiento*" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Nacionalidad:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('nacionalidad') }}" placeholder="Ingrese la nacionalidad del Coordinador*" name="nacionalidad" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Apellido:') !!}
            <select required class="form-control" value="{{ old('sexo') }}" name="sexo" id="">
                <option value="">Seleccione el Sexo del Coord. Adm.</option>
                <option value="M" @if(old('sexo') == 'M') selected @endif>Masculino</option>
                <option value="F" @if(old('sexo') == 'F') selected @endif>Femenino</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Sede:') !!}
            <select required class="form-control" value="{{ old('Sede') }}" name="Sede" id="selectTipo">
                <option selected value="">Seleccion Sede</option>
                @foreach($sede as $user)
                    <option value="{{$user->idSede}}" @if(old('Sede') == $user->idSede) selected @endif>{{$user->nombre}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>          

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-5 col-xs-12 " id="home">
        <p></p>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Teléfono Celular:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Ingrese el número de Télf. Celular*" name="telefono_celular" value="{{ old('telefono_celular') }}" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Teléfono Oficina:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Ingrese el número de Télf. Oficina" value="{{ old('telefono_oficina') }}" name="telefono_oficina">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Teléfono Casa:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control " placeholder="Ingrese el número de Télf. Casa" value="{{ old('telefono_casa') }}" name="telefono_casa">
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Fecha Inicio Cargo:') !!}
            <input type="date" class="form-control" step="1" min="1907-01-01" name="fecha_inicio" value="{{ old('fecha_inicio') }}" id="fecha_ini" placeholder="Seleccione la fecha de Inicio en el cargo*" required>
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Fecha Fin Cargo:') !!}
            <input type="date" class="form-control" step="1" min="1907-01-01" value="{{ old('fecha_fin') }}" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" placeholder="Seleccione la fecha de Fin en el cargo*">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('Razón Cambio:') !!}
             <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ old('razon_cambio') }}" placeholder="Ingrese la Razón del cambio" name="razon_cambio">
        </div>

    </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4" id="fondo">
                <div id="margenbotonAgregar">
                    <center><button  type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block btn-lg"><span  class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Agregar Cod. Adminsitrativo</button></center>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
    {!!Form::close()!!}
 </div>
 @endsection

@section('scriptFooter')
<script>
    $(function (){
        $('#selectTipo').on('change',buscarUbicacion);
    });

    function  buscarUbicacion() {
    var tipo= $(this).val();
    $.get('/buscarSede/'+tipo+'/pertenece', function (data)
        {   
            //alert(data[0].fecha_apertura);
            $("#fecha_ini").val(data[0].fecha_apertura);
        });
    }
 </script>
@endsection
```

[image: Estos son los valores que se ingresan]

[image: A pesar de que se muestra el alert con el mensaje, los campos no se vuelven a recargar con los datos anteriormente pasados]

Answer (score 1):

primero no necesitas `redirect()->back()->withInput()`

simplemente `back()->withInput()` prueba eso y si no prueba esto:

`back()->withInput($request->all())`

Puedes ver mas soluciones de esto en este link

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081644/how-to-redirect-back-to-form-with-input-laravel-5

Comment: Si, lo coloco de esa manera, la pagina no se va hacia atrás, si no que se queda en una página en blanco.

Comment: `return back()->withInput();`

Comment: nada, no vuelve a colocar los valores en el input